# Error doble de conexión al hacer git pull

Tags: git, bitbucket

estoy experimentando el siguiente mensaje de error al realizar un git pull en linea de comandos:

```
$ git pull origin master
fatal: Error al enviar la solicitud.
fatal: Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de recepción.
fatal: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.
fatal: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
fatal: Error al enviar la solicitud.
fatal: Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de recepción.
fatal: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.
fatal: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
From https://xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx/bitbucket/scm/area/proyecto
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

Estoy buscando en Google los mensajes de error, tanto en español como los que podrían ser en inglés y no encuentro en ninguno de los dos idiomas una reproducción de este error.

Parece que al final, git resuelve la operación, pero quisiera saber a que se debe el error y si puede solucionarse, dado que parece lejos de ser un warning.

Comment: El servidor cerró la conexión. Deberias ir a ver en el servidor qué fue lo que pasó.

Comment: No lo llevo yo. Y antes de que nos puedan prestar atención los que lo llevan puede pasar un tiempo considerable.